# Excel SUMIF formula needed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a SUMIF formula which adds up all values of a column if the row meets a certain criteria. The criteria is that it needs to match either of the 3 categories (A, B or C). My data looks like this:

```
A     5     4
B    32     4
B    12     6
B     4     7
A    21   342
C     2     2
C     1     1
A     3     5

A   <total A> <total A> etc
B   <total B> <total B> etc
C   <total C> <total C> etc
```

The formula should work when dragged horizontally.

[image: Screenshot of an example table]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mike Meinz gave you the right answer. Formula could be simplified like the following:

In Column B totals for criteria A, B and C can be calculated as following:

```
=SUMIF($A1:$A8,"A",$B1:$B8) 
=SUMIF($A1:$A8,"B",$B1:$B8)
=SUMIF($A1:$A8,"C",$B1:$B8)
```

Note: absolute reference ($) is used to make the value stay the same if cell is dragged horizontally, as per your requirement.

In case you would like to calculate the totals of **current** column after the cell was dragged (rather than **fixed** one, i.e. column B in this example), modify the formula like:

=SUMIF($A1:$A8,"A",B1:B8)

Correspondingly, similar syntax can be applied to Column C.
Regards,

Comment: use `B1:B8` to drag the formula horizontally - the point is to calculate the current column, not always column B

Answer (score 1):

In Column B

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$8,"=A",B$1:B$8)
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$8,"=B",B$1:B$8)
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$8,"=C",B$1:B$8)
```

In Column C

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$8,"=A",C$1:C$8)
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$8,"=B",C$1:C$8)
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$8,"=C",C$1:C$8)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've found =SUMIF($A1:$A8,"A",$B1:$B8) to work better, like @Alex Bell posted too. Thanks guys!