# Excel sum without specific rows

Tags: excel, sum, formula, rows

I need help with creating sum formula on Excel sheet.

I need on excel show sum formula **without specific rows**. In these rows for example is word "W" or something other way. And I need show sum for example:

```
=SUM(A1:A5) ........ without if column E have = "W"
```

I tried checkbox solution, but I finding other better solution:

[image: excel example image]

Please can you help me, how can I do it?

EDIT :

i also posting you my excel sheet what i tried from your solution, but not working:

[example of excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMpgI.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel SUMIF formula needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824467/excel-sumif-formula-needed)

Comment: Just modify your code like this - `=SUMIF(E1:E5;"<>"&"W";A1:A5)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SUMIF` formula to only sum column A if the column E has a value of W like below:

```
=SUMIF(E:E,"w",A:A)
```

Comment: Not sure about your regional settings, but you may need to replace the commas (,) in my formula for semi colons(;)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like `=SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(E1:E5="W")),A1:A5)`.  Sumproduct multiplies everything in one column with everything in another, and sums the results. `--` converts a boolean statement into a 1 or a 0.

So, with this formula, you would be multiplying each item in column A with either a 1 or a 0.  Obviously, things multiplied by zero do not have any effect on the final sum :)

Comment: =SUMIF(E1:E5;"<>W";A1:A5)